# Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
     @date1 Date = '2011-06-01'
   ,@date2 Date ='2016-06-30'
   ,@StoreNo Nvarchar(Max)=' '
As 
Begin
Select 
       STD.StoreNo As StoreNo
       ,CheckDate As CheckDate
      ,ProductBarCode as ProductBarCode
     ,  SUM( case
    when Lead(STD.StockTakingQty) over ( order by STD.StockTakingQty) is null  
        and [CheckDate] <> EOMONTH([CheckDate])
      then STD.[StockTakingQty]
    else STD.[StockTakingQty] - lead(STD.[StockTakingQty]) over ( order by STD.StockTakingQty)
  end)AS ProducQty
    Into ##temp
     From StockTakingDetail STD
Inner Join
(Select StoreNo,CheckNo,CheckDate 
              From StockTakingMain SM )StocktakingMain 
   On STD.CheckNo =StockTakingMain.CheckNo

   Where  
  CheckDate Between @date1 AND @date2 

  Group by 
        STD.StoreNo,ProductBarCode,CheckDate

If EXISTS (Select StoreNo from ##temp)

Begin 

Declare @sql Nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = N'Select * from ##temp where 1=1 ' +@StoreNo+ 'Order By StoreNo,ProductBarcode'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
END

Else 

BEGIN
SELECT
      ' ' as StoreNo
      ,'' as CheckDate
      ,'' as ProductBarCode
      ,0 as ProductQty

End

DRop Table ##temp

End
```

I was trying for Daily Inventory and Every month once they you to take inventory but I have to show everyday inventory can't be leave Null value there.

Comment: I removed the "mysqli" tag and replaced it with SQL Server, because the syntax is clearly SQL Server.  Also, you should attempt to simplify your query.  As written it is very hard to follow and determine where the error might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use `LEAD` inside the `SUM` - that is why you are getting error. Instead of `LEAD` use `OUTER APPLY` to get next value you need.

```
Select  STD.StoreNo As StoreNo,
        CheckDate As CheckDate,
        ProductBarCode as ProductBarCode,
        SUM(case 
                when s.StockTakingQty is null and [CheckDate] <> EOMONTH([CheckDate])
                then STD.[StockTakingQty]
                else STD.[StockTakingQty] - s.StockTakingQty
            end) AS ProducQty
Into ##temp
From StockTakingDetail STD
Inner Join (
    Select  StoreNo,
            CheckNo,
            CheckDate 
    From StockTakingMain SM
    )StocktakingMain 
    On STD.CheckNo =StockTakingMain.CheckNo
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM StockTakingDetail
    WHERE SomeIDfield = STD.SomeIDfield
    ORDER BY StockTakingQty 
    ) s
Where CheckDate Between @date1 AND @date2 
Group by STD.StoreNo,ProductBarCode,CheckDate
```